# onWebView No views in hierarchy found matching: WebView with JS enabled

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying some basic webView testing:

```
public class TheMainActivity {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class, false, false) {
        @Override
        protected void afterActivityLaunched() {
            onWebView().forceJavascriptEnabled();
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void theIntroductionShouldShow() {
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(null);
        onWebView().check(webMatches(getText(), containsString("SURVIVAL ACTIONS")));
    }
}
```

regarding to this documentation - but I get:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: WebView with JS enabled

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1776, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1776, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909140, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1701, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=75.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->ActionBarOverlayLayout{id=2131492956, res-name=decor_content_parent, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1701, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1533, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=168.0, child-count=2}
|
+----->DrawerLayout{id=2131492973, res-name=drawer_layout, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1533, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>CoordinatorLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1533, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->WebView{id=2131492974, res-name=webView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1533, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true, editor-info=[inputType=0x0 imeOptions=0x0 privateImeOptions=null actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=null label=null packageName=null fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null ], x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+------>NavigationView{id=2131492975, res-name=navigationView, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=840, height=1533, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=-840.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->NavigationMenuView{id=2131492981, res-name=design_navigation_view, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=1533, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=12}
|
+-------->LinearLayout{id=2131492980, res-name=navigation_header_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=24, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=24.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Introduction, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=168.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Psychology, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=312.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Planning and Kits, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=456.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Basic Medicine, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=600.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Shelter, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=744.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Water, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=888.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Fire, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1032.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Food, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1176.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Plants, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1320.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Poisonous Plants, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-------->NavigationMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=840, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1464.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->AppCompatCheckedTextView{id=2131492982, res-name=design_menu_item_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=744, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=0.0, text=Animals, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+--------->ViewStub{id=2131492983, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+----->SnackbarLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1400.2982, child-count=2}
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=2131492978, res-name=snackbar_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=826, height=141, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=36.0, y=1.0, text=Like?, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>AppCompatButton{id=2131492979, res-name=snackbar_action, visibility=VISIBLE, width=182, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=862.0, y=0.0, text=Rate!, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---->ActionBarContainer{id=2131492957, res-name=action_bar_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+----->Toolbar{id=2131492958, res-name=action_bar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=431, height=81, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=216.0, y=12.0, text=Survival Manual, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>AppCompatImageButton{id=-1, desc=open, visibility=VISIBLE, width=168, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=259, height=63, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=216.0, y=93.0, text=Introduction, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>ActionMenuView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=144, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=936.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->ActionMenuItemView{id=2131492999, res-name=menu_help, desc=Introduction, visibility=VISIBLE, width=144, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=12.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+----->ActionBarContextView{id=2131492959, res-name=action_context_bar, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:591)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.forceJavascriptEnabled(Web.java:136)
at org.ligi.survivalmanual.TheSurvivalActivity$1.afterActivityLaunched(TheSurvivalActivity.java:19)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:225)
at org.ligi.survivalmanual.TheSurvivalActivity.theIntroductionShouldShow(TheSurvivalActivity.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)

Tests ran to completion.
```

Interestingly when I set javascript enabled in the MainActivity ( allthough I do not want this and forceJavascriptEnabled() should do it for the test regarding the documentation ) then I this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Assertion failed: Node cannot be null or undefined.} hasMessage: true message: Assertion failed: Node cannot be null or undefined.
at android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction$ExceptionPropagator.<init>(Web.java:323)
at android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.doEval(Web.java:292)
at android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.check(Web.java:273)
at org.ligi.survivalmanual.TheSurvivalActivity.theIntroductionShouldShow(TheSurvivalActivity.java:26)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
```

...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `onWebView()` method use as view matcher `isJavascriptEnabled()` and this can't match until you activate it. Instead you can call `onWebView(myMatcher)` and then it should work. The espresso documentation looks a bit incorrect here.

For your second error message I have no explanation yet.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Forget what I wrote earlier ;)

Comment: thanks this really helped - but I cannot award you the bounty yet - so does not allow

Comment: Could you add an answer of how to set this up using myMatcher?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @nenick's answer a bit... He is correct `forceJavascriptEnabled` won't work until the correct view is found. So as he said, you add a matcher to the `onWebView` call. For example, I used the webview id but you could use a matcher that is appropriate to your situation.

Example:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MyActivity>(MyActivity.class, false, false) {
    @Override
    protected void afterActivityLaunched() {
        onWebView(withId(R.id.target_webview)).forceJavascriptEnabled();
    }
};
```

Hope that helps clarify the accepted answer a bit.