# How to access elements on external website using Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-uiautomator, chrome-custom-tabs, android-espresso-recorder

Using espresso, we click a Login button which launches an external website (Chrome Custom Tab) where you can login and then it redirects back to our android application.

Is there a way in Espresso to:
1) Verify the correct URL is being launched
2) Access the elements on the website so that I can enter the login information and continue to login

[image]

When I try viewing it in the Espresso Launch Navigator, nothing shows up for the page, and if I try to record, it doesn't pick up on me entering anything on the page.

This is what I have so far (it is in Kotlin (not Java)):
[image]

And here is the error that gets displayed:
[image]

It launches my application, select the login button, opens the website but then it isn't able to access the elements.

I also tried:

[image]

Update: This is using Chrome Custom Tabs (not a Web View) so Espresso Web is not working.

Comment: Please post you code as plain text next time, not as images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using both Espresso and UI Automator.  You are able to combine the two.  The selection of the login button I used Espresso (and the rest of the app, I will use Espresso).  To handle the Chrome Custom tab for logging in, I used UIAutomator:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so, so much. I never would have figured out having to press the same button twice like that. How did you figure it out, and why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: Are you referring to the sign in button?  It is actually clicking a sign in header first and then the sign in button but i had to do that because i needed it to dismiss the keyboard that comes up.  The keyboard was covering the sign in button so i clicked an element elsewhere on the screen first to get it to go away and then i could access the sign in button.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! You made me realize that I was having the same issue, but it worked because my selector wasn't specific enough and was clicking something different than I thought it was. Now I can use a different, more obvious selector.

Comment: how are you clicking on the button in the webpage using UIautomator ? I'm trying to click on the button in webpage but I'm not able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

You can't use Espresso for testing Chrome Custom Tabs. Espresso works when testing your own app.

For testing the Chrome tabs you could use [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) but you probably don't want to do that.

> 1) Verify the correct URL is being launched

A unit test would be enough here. You just need to make sure the URL passed to the Chrome custom tabs library is the correct one. You are making sure YOUR code works fine. What happens next is handled by the library and the tests belong there.

> 2) Access the elements on the website so that I can enter the login
>   information and continue to login

Here you are testing a simple web page. Why would you like the additional overhead of starting an emulator? Maybe [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or whatever is cool for web would work here (not a web dev)?

You can use [Espresso Web](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/web.html)

Here is an example test:

```
@Test
public void typeTextInInput_clickButton_SubmitsForm() {
    // Lazily launch the Activity with a custom start Intent per test.
    mActivityRule.launchActivity(withWebFormIntent());

    // Selects the WebView in your layout. If you have multiple WebView objects,
    // you can also use a matcher to select a given WebView,
    // onWebView(withId(R.id.web_view)).
    onWebView()
        // Find the input element by ID.
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "text_input"))
        // Clear previous input.
        .perform(clearElement())
        // Enter text into the input element.
        .perform(DriverAtoms.webKeys(MACCHIATO))
        // Find the submit button.
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "submitBtn"))
        // Simulate a click using JavaScript.
        .perform(webClick())
        // Find the response element by ID.
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "response"))
        // Verify that the response page contains the entered text.
        .check(webMatches(getText(), containsString(MACCHIATO)));
}
```

Comment: What is the withWebFormIntent()?  Also, I have the app launched already using the LaunchActivity then I select the Login button and that is when I want it to use a web view.

Comment: If i try to launch it with JS enabled (in the override for afterActivityLaunched) it gives me: android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: WebView with JS enabled

Comment: Updated question with more information on what I currently have

Comment: @rfodge check this for your second comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558202/onwebview-no-views-in-hierarchy-found-matching-webview-with-js-enabled

Comment: I tried that solution (unless something is incorrect still with my setup). See examples of what i tried in the question.  I have two screenshots with using a matcher.

Comment: I updated my question, but the web view does not work because I found out we are using a chrome custom tab not a web view for it.

Comment: Why do you say we wouldn't want to use UI Automator?  Is there a particular con to trying that?  I start up the emulator already for testing.  I launch our application in an emulator, select our login button, and then I need to login (via the chrome custom tab), and then we get redirected back to our application to login.

Comment: @reutsey,  did you find the solution for this issue? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: @LordRaydenMK - What exactly this withWebFormIntent()? How to get this method?

Comment: @KeshavKumar you can find that in https://github.com/android/testing-samples/blob/38155c782fca4730e9553a5ae6e98d9f04897999/ui/espresso/WebBasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/web/BasicSample/WebViewActivityTest.java#L130